# Fetching radio button value from db and also wants the radio button to be checked

Tags: php, mysql

I have one radio button of gender. The value is getting stored in db and i am able to fetch it too. But I want the radio button to be checked for the received value. Help me.

```html
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" > Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked> Female
```

Comment: Add the `checked` attribute to the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work as follow

```
<?php
 $db_value = 'male'; // this is the value from db
?>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if($db_value == 'male'):?>checked<?php endif;?>> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if($db_value == 'female'):?>checked<?php endif;?>> Female
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check which `radiobutton` should be selected by using `if-else statement` like below where `$row['gender']` is column where radiobutton value is there :

```
    <?php  if($row['gender']== 'male') { ?>

    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male

   <?php  }else { ?>

     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" checked> Female

   <?php } ?>
```